# Trouble installing php-devel on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, php, php-apc

Working with a PHP install and trying to install APC on a server to help with speed issues with an application we're developing.

We are having trouble getting phpize installed. phpize is not on the server currently. However, when I try a sudo yum install php-devel, it gives me the error:

```
"Loaded plugins: security Setting up Install Process Package
php-devel-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do"
```

Not sure what I need to do from here. Could someone help me out? Thanks!

> (***please note - this question was closed in an earlier post and it was
>   marked as "off topic". I'm not sure why. I am a programmer trying to
>   install a programming tool (php-devel). So, I would assume this would
>   be the correct place to receive assistance. Please let me know if I am
>   wrong about that. Thanks!)

Comment: @ShivanRaptor While I endorse the usage of SuperUser, a lot of these questions is accepted to be posted on StackOverflow if it's seen from a developers point of view. If this specific question is could be discussed, of course.